# How to upgrade a module already distributed with Drupal Commerce?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce

Drupal Commerce 1 has included Crumbs 1.10.
I need to upgrade Crumbs to 2.7, and this version isn't included with Drupal Commerce.

How can I upgrade it without breaking Drupal Commerce distribution (and update) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Composer Package Management:**

If you are using Composer to manage the installed modules/distributions for your Drupal 7 site, you can set the minimum version constraint and then run composer update for the Crumbs module:

```
composer require 'drupal/crumbs:^2.7'
composer update 'drupal/crumbs'
```

**Traditional/Legacy code repositories:**

For traditional/legacy code repositories that don't use composer, you can:

1. Backup your database/codebase
2. Download the desired version of the module
3. replace the older version of the module (typically found in your codebase's /profiles/contrib/commerce/modules/ directory or /modules/contrib/ directory).
4. Deploy the updated module code.
5. Run update.php or `drush updatedb`.
6. Clear caches.

In the case that the Drupal Commerce profile has a fixed version dependency for Crumbs 1.10, you should be able to update the version constraint in the .info file for the module.

Comment: I use the traditional code repository.
If i follow your steps, the next Drupal Commerce update will remove my crumbs update. Is is possible to put it anywhere else in order to not get this conflict? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drush command as follow to update a specific version of module.

```
$ drush pm-update views_send-7.x-1.x-dev
```

Thanks